# Regex Java word context

Tags: java, regex, string

what I want to achieve is that I want to obtain the context of an acronym. Can you help me pls with the regular expression?

I am looping over the text (String) and looking for dots, after match I am trying to get the context of the particular found acronym, so that I can do some other processing after that, but I cant get the context. I need to take at least 5 words before and 5 words after the acronym.

```
//Pattern to match each word ending with dot
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\b([.])");


    Matcher matchDot = pattern.matcher(textToCorrect);
    while (matchDot.find()) {
        System.out.println("zkratka ---"+matchDot.group()+" ---");


        //5 words before and after tha match = context
     //   Matcher matchContext = Pattern.compile("(.{25})("+matchDot.group()+")(.{25})").matcher(textToCorrect);
        Pattern patternContext = Pattern.compile("(?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,10}"+matchDot.group()+"(?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,10}");
        Matcher matchContext = patternContext.matcher(textToCorrect);
        if (matchContext.find()) {              
             System.out.println("context: "+matchContext.group()+" :");

    //       System.out.println("context: "+matchContext.group(1)+" :");
    //       System.out.println("context: "+matchContext.group(2)+" :");
        }

    }
```

Example:

input:
Some 84% of Paris residents see fighting pol. as a priority and 54% supported a diesel ban in the city by 2020, according a poll carried out for the Journal du Dimanche.

output:
1-st regex will find **pol.**
2-nd regex will find "**of Paris residents see fighting** *pol.* **as a priority and 54%**"

Another example with more text

I need to loop through this once and every time I match an acronym to get the context of this particular acronym. After that I am processing some datamining. Here's the original text

> neklidná nemocná, vyš. je možné provést pouze nativně
>
> Na mozku je patrna hyperdenzita v počátečním úseku a. cerebri media
>   vlevo, vlevo se objevuje již smazání hranic mezi bazálními ganglii a
>   okolní bílou hmotou a mírná difuzní hypointenzita v periventrikulární
>   bílé hmotě. Kromě těchto čerstvých změn jsou patrné  staré
>   postmalatické změny temporálně a parietookcipitálně vlevo. Oboustranně
>   jsou patrné vícečetné vaskulární mikroléze v centrum semiovale bilat.
>   Nejsou známky nitrolebního krvácení. skelet kalvy orientačně nihil tr.
>
> Z á v ě r: Známky hyperakutní ischemie v povodí ACM vlevo, staré
>   postmalatickéé změny T,P a O vlevo, vaskulární mikroléze v centrum
>   semiovale bilat.
>
> CT AG: vyš. po bolu k.l..
>
> Po zklidnění nemocné se podařilo provést CT AG. Na krku je naznačený
>   kinkink na ACC vlevo a ACI vlevo pod bazí. Kalcifikace  v karotických
>   sifonech nepůsobí hemodynamicky významné stenozy. Intrakraniálně je
>   patrný konický uzávěr operkulárního úseku a. cerebri media vlevo pro
>   parietální lalok. Ostatní nález na intrakraniálním tepenném řečišti je
>   v mezích normy.
>
> Z á v ě r: uzávěr operkulárního úseku a. cerebri media vlevo.

Of course if it matches end of sentence is ok for me :-) The question is to find all the acronyms even if they are before new line (\n)

Comment: Can you post some input and expected output

Comment: To do that you need to have a predefined list of acronyms, it's not possible to deduce that a substring is an acronym by its format.

Comment: its hard to have all of them, because my task was to autocomplete the acronyms, so there is no way how to have a defined list of them. Nevertheless if I autocomplete at least 70% of them it will be a big success.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
((?:[\w!@#$%&*]+\s+){5}([\w!@#$%&*]+\.)(?:\s+[\w!@#$%&*]+){5})
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/aQ3zJ3/9

Comment: it works, but let's assume that I have longer text with much more acronyms and alot of dots, this won't work. I need it to be more abstract with dynamic acronym word in the middle. That's why I have the found acronym in the middle of my second regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this out:

```
(?:\w+\W+){5}((?:\w.?)+)(?:\w+\W+){5}
```

Though natural language processing with regular expressions cannot be accurate.