# Regex for start and end of sentence

Tags: java, regex, string

Is there a way to match **start** and **end** of sentence in Java? The easiest case is ending with simple (.) dot. In some other cases it could end with colum (:) or a shortcut ended with colum (.:).

For example some random news text:

> Cliffs have collapsed in New Zealand during an earthquake in the city
> of Christchurch on the South Island. No serious damage or fatalities
> were reported in the Valentine's Day quake that struck at 13:13 local
> time. Based on the **med.** report everybody were ok.

My goal is to get the shortcut of a word + the context of it, but if possible only the sentence in which the shortcut belonds.

So the successfull output for me will be if I would be able to get something like this:

> **selected word** -> collapsed
>
> **context** -> Cliffs have collapsed in New Zealand during an earthquake in the city of Christchurch on the South Island.
>
> **selected word** -> med.
>
> **context** -> Based on the **med.** report everybody were ok.

Thanks

Comment: No regex, sorry. You need more powerful tool.

Comment: Any suggestions or where to start from?

Comment: You should find some english language grammar analyzer, you need to know the context. I think this will be hard job to write it yourself unless you find existing library.

Comment: But if you are OK with some mistakes then regexp can do decent job as well.

Comment: What came first up to my mind was to get the raw context [5 words before] selected word [5 words after] based on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27346080/regex-java-word-context/27346239#27346239, but I would like to be more precise

Comment: I would search for previous occurence of dot followed by space and capitol word and next occurence of the same pattern. You should check start/end of text and elipis  (..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You spot the sentence easily. It starts with a capital letter and ends with one of `.:!?` chars followed by space and another capital letter or reached the end of the whole string.

Compare the difference `time. Based` and `med. report`.

So the regex capturing the whole sentence should look like this:

```
([A-Z][a-z].*?[.:!?](?=$| [A-Z]))
```

Take a look! [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jK5mP3/1)

Comment: May I ask if this answer be robust to proper nouns?  That is, if `America` appeared in the middle of a sentence, what would happen?

Answer (score 3):

what you are looking for is a natural language processing toolkit. for java you can use: [CoreNLP](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/)
and they already have some example cases on their tutorials page.
you can certainly make a regex expression that looks for all chars inbetween the set of chars (.:? etc...), and it would look something like this:

```
\.*?(?=[\.\:])\
```

then you would have to loop through the matched results and find the relevant sentences which have your words in them. but i recommend you use a NLP to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

**The code:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      final Map<String, String> dict = new HashMap<>();
      dict.put( "med", "medical" );
      final String text =
         "Cliffs have collapsed in New Zealand during an earthquake in the "
         + "city of Christchurch on the South Island. No serious damage or "
         + "fatalities were reported in the Valentine's Day quake that struck "
         + "at 13:13 local time. Based on the med. report everybody were ok.";
      final Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "[^\\.]+\\W+(\\w+)\\." );
      final Matcher m = p.matcher( text );
      int pos = 0;
      while(( pos < text.length()) && m.find( pos )) {
         pos = m.end() + 1;
         final String word = m.group( 1 );
         if( dict.containsKey( word )) {
            final String repl            = dict.get( word );
            final String beginOfSentence = text.substring( m.start(), m.end());
            final String endOfSentence;
            if( m.find( pos )) {
               endOfSentence = text.substring( m.start() - 1, m.end());
            }
            else {
               endOfSentence = text.substring( m.start() - 1);
            }
            System.err.printf( "Replace '%s.' in '%s%s' with '%s'\n",
               word, beginOfSentence, endOfSentence, repl );
            final String sentence =
               ( beginOfSentence + endOfSentence ).replaceAll( word+'.', repl );
            System.err.println( sentence );
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**The execution:**

```
Replace 'med.' in 'Based on the med. report everybody were ok.' with 'medical'
Based on the medical report everybody were ok.
```

Comment: I think you should underline the fact that it needs all abbreviations in the text to be known beforehand, which is far from trivial. Also I think it would fail were the text to contain decimal numbers.

Comment: I feel that modifying all the shortened words is a nonsence. Therefore you cannot apply it to any text without manually updating your dictionary.